# Como hacer una inserción, y que sea consecutiva

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Estoy trabajando con C# (ASP.NET)mi proyecto trata sobre inserción de folios y al llegar el día 1ro del mes, el contador inserta 1, pero lo que quiero realizar es que solo inserte una vez el numero 1 y el siguiente sea su consecutivo y así hasta llegar de nuevo al siguiente corte, solo eh logrado que se inserte el 1 pero no su consecutivo. adjunto código de ejemplo:

```
 protected void aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int count = int.Parse(folioTextBox.Text);
    count++;
    folioTextBox.Text = count.ToString();
    fechaTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    string fol = folioTextBox.Text;
    string fecha = fechaTextBox.Text;
    string fechaopr = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
    string fechanw = "01";

    conexion.Open();



    if (fechaopr == fechanw)
    {
        string cadena1 = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values ('1','" + fecha + "')";
        SqlCommand comando1 = new SqlCommand(cadena1, conexion);
        comando1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        string cadena = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values ('" + fol + "','" + fecha + "')";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    respuestaLabel.Text = ("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
    conexion.Close();

}
```

Y mi ejemplo en la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No mires si es 30/31 o 28 de Febrero, eso es muy complicado. Mira si es día 1, que todos los meses tienen día 1.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster que tal como desarrollarías eso, ya que hay que tomar en cuenta el día primero de cada mes y en cuanto comience el año 2020

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que recuperar el ultimo folio consultando la db, para eso primero realizas un `SELECT` con el `MAX` y en el filtro por mes

[MONTH (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

la funcion quedaria

```
private int GetLastFolio(int mes)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT MAX(Folio) FROM <Tabla> WHERE MONTH(Mes) = @mes"; 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", mes); 

        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 

    } 
}
```

entonces lo usas

```
protected void aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int folio = GetLastFolio(DateTime.Now.Month);

    string sql = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values (@folio, @fecha)"; 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
    { 
        conn.Open(); 

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", folio); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Now); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    } 

    respuestaLabel.Text = ("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
}
```

usa siempre parametros, concatener los valores en un string no es buena practica

Comment: Que tal Leandro,estuve realizando tu ejemplo y en mi base de datos me arroja el numero 9 en el campo "Folio" quise colocar una imagen de ejemplo pero no pude lograrlo, busco realizar que cuando sea día 1 del mes el contador regrese a 1

Answer (score 0):

La forma en que yo manejo fechas en C# es la siguiente:

Para saber el día actual

```
DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now; //La fecha de hoy`
```

Primer día del mes:

```
DateTime primeroDeMes = new DateTime(hoy.Year, hoy.Month, 1);
```

Último día del mes actual:

```
DateTime ultimoDia = primeroDeMes.Value.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

A partir de estos datos ya puedes hacer todas las operaciones que necesites, sólo tendrías que extraer el día, mes o año que requieras de la fecha creada.